# waited for 30s and no inital state set by the discorery error run ElasticSearch 1.3.2 on ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I tried to run the latest ElasticSearch 1.3.2 on ubuntu 14.04, but encountered an error.

> waited for 30s and no inital state set by the discovery

I enabled DEBUG logging level in command line `./elasticsearch  -Des.logger.level=DEBUG`  to start ElasticSearch. And got the more info.

> [2014-09-04 15:45:46,247][WARN ][discovery                ] [Sigyn] waited for 30s and no  initial state was set by the discovery
>   [2014-09-04 15:45:46,247][DEBUG][gateway                  ] [Sigyn] can't wait on start > for (possibly) reading state from gateway, will do it asynchronously

After some time for this waiting, and then it will try to connect 192.168.1.100:9300.

I am using Oracle JDK 8 and used the default config for the ElasticSearch.

In my project, I used Spring Data ElasticSearch to process the elasticsearch operations, it will report an exception "MasterNotDiscoveredException".

> Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.elasticsearch.discovery.MasterNotDiscoveredException: waited for [30s]

But I used ElasticSearch 1.3.2 on Windows 7/JDK8 update20, everything worked well.

Is there any extra steps needed under Linux system?

Comment: I encountered the same problem when trying to connect from a Mac running Java 8 and trying to connect to an elasticsearch cluster running on CentOS 6.x.